# File is not creating in python when unicode present in the file name

Tags: python

I need to store HTML file as text files. In the same name of web tittle. something went wrong with my code so that it is not creating file in side the directory.  I have directory permission to write. I am using Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Directory `/home/user1/`
File name
print name = Mathrubhumi Sports - ശ്രീനിക്ക് പച്ചക്കൊടി

The file name contain Unicode values

```
  import os
    from urllib import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    url= "http://www.mathrubhumi.com/sports/story.php?id=397111"
    raw = urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(raw,'lxml')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    name = soup.title.text
    name= name+'.txt'
    def contains_unicode(text):
        try:
            str(text)
        except:
            return True
        return False

    result = ''.join((text for text in texts if contains_unicode(text)))

    # Output to a file
    with open(os.path.join('/home/user1/textfiles',name,'w') as out:
        out.write(result)
```

Please help me to debug it

Comment: Permission for localization?

Comment: Do you get any error? Which?

Comment: Yes, I have permission to write

Comment: in which directory ? what the value of `name` is ? print it

Comment: maybe no lines contain unicode?

Comment: @carlosdc he says the file is not created, not that the file is empty or with wrong characters

Comment: @joaquin: yes, but it is strange that he's not getting an error

Comment: Print the value of name, and try setting it to something you know is good and see if that file is created

Comment: @carlosdc maybe he is not looking at the correct directory...

Comment: /home/user1/  <title>Mathrubhumi Sports - ശ്രീനിക്ക് പച്ചക്കൊടി
</title>

Comment: you can't create a file with a /, for example

Comment: @carlosdc my file name is this  Mathrubhumi Sports - ശ്രീനിക്ക് പച്ചക്കൊടി

Comment: why did you write </title>?

Comment: @carlosdc while printing the  tittle I am getting the same

Comment: @DavidSykes Yes, It is working when I tried in your way. It is creating file

Comment: This code is dangerous. `name` could end up being anything, for example a full filesystem path, and you might overwrite important files in your file system.

Comment: @Kos How can I fix it?

Comment: @Kos  like this  with open(os.path.join('/home/user1/textfiles',name,'w') as out:
        out.write(result)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a very specific topic, unlikely to provide value for any future visitor of stackoverflow

Comment: @twiddles. it would be useful for people working with Unicode

Comment: Yes, but they won't find it. The question title is misleading regarding the actual problem and it is tagged with `file` and `beautifoul soup`. My point was (when reviewing this question) that there is too much "background noise" regarding the real problem you faced. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: @twiddles I am going to some  make changes now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it worked, it created a file called Mathrub*.txt with some text in it in the current directory.

```
import codecs
import os
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url= "http://www.mathrubhumi.com/sports/story.php?id=397111"
raw = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw,'lxml')
texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
name = soup.title.string
name= name+'.txt'
def contains_unicode(text):
    try:
        str(text)
    except:
        return True
    return False

result = ''.join((text for text in texts if contains_unicode(text)))
# Output to a file
with codecs.open(name,'w',encoding="utf-8") as out:
    out.write(result)
```

Before adding the codecs part, it complained loudly about trying to write some characters that it did not know how to interpret.